# Bash echo $-1 prints hb1. Why?

Tags: bash, arguments, variable-substitution

If I ask bash to echo the -1th argument it prints hb1:

```
echo $-1
hb1
```

Why? What is it accessing?

Comment: `$-` gets the current shell options (which is apparently "hb"). What did you expect it to do?

Comment: I thought it might loop round like some arrays do. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are not asking it to print the 1st argument, that would be: `$1`.

What you are asking for is a [special parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters):

> `-`
>
> > (`$-`, a hyphen.) Expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, by the set builtin command, or those set by the shell itself (such as the -i option).

So your options are: `hb`

Then you see the `1` you've added is printed afterwards (hence `hb1`).

---

If you are looking to get the last argument (Not sure if that is what you meant by -1 argument), you can use [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the following form:

```
$ set -- one two three
$ echo "${@: -1}"
three
```

Comment: `${!#}` is also the value of the last parameter, using indirect expansion.

Comment: Hmmm: `${@:~0}` and `eval echo \$$#` are also the last argument. :-)

Comment: @Isaac If you're *lucky*, that's true. If `IFS` contains any digits in the value `$#` expands to, not so much. Always safer to quote; `eval "echo \"\$$#\""` is more reliable. To see the failure for yourself: `IFS=1234567890; set -- one two three; eval echo \$$#` only outputs `$`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, you are correct, my mistake. But it is also required to allow positional parameters at position 10 and up. For a really reliable solution add **{}** : `IFS=1234567890; set -- {a..w}; eval echo \"\$\{"$#"\}\"` ;-)